# How to add a text under the image button in Android?

Tags: android, button, imagebutton

I want to add text under a image button, which are also clickable, and will be redirected to the same activity as the image button. basically it's like the app list in any android phone, e.g.[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have your `ImageButton` declared in XML, then just put it into a `LinearLayout` which also contains a `TextView` and set the `onClickListener` on the `LinearLayout`. The structure would be like

```
<LinearLayout 
      ... > <!-- This is the LinearLayout for the xml document -->

    <!-- Some other layout code here if you please -->
    <LinearLayout 
       android:id="@+id/linLayout"
            ... >
         <ImageButton
               ... />
         <TextView
               ... />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And then in your java:

```java
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linLayout);
layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

If you're adding each `ImageButton` dynamically via java code, then it will still maintain the same structure. Let me know if I need to add anything.

Comment: I tried that, it makes textview clickable, but suddenly the imagebutton does not work after click. I have to keep the onclicklistener code for imagebutton in the .java file as well to make both imagebutton and text clickable

Comment: You're doing it wrong then. If the LinearLayout containing a particular item is set to listen to the click then the image, nor the text are being listened to. ONLY the layout that contains all these views.

Comment: I know this is an old post, however I had the same issue as Xiao Han above (the TextView was clickable but the ImageButton was not). I changed the ImageButton to an ImageView and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 11):

setAlpha and do the below

```xml
<Button
    android:id="@+id/comparePack"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:onClick="compareButtonClick"
    android:text="@string/compare" 
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/compare1edit"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical" />
```

Comment: unfortunately this method has no control on image scale!

Answer (score 1):

if you want to create this king of list use gridview 
and in getview method inflate customlayout with imageview and textview

Answer (score 0):

Also you can set onClickListener to TextView

```
<!-- Some other layout code here if you please -->
<LinearLayout 
   android:id="@+id/linLayout"
        ... >
     <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btn1"
           ... />
     <TextView android:id="@+id/tv1"
           ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

java code:

```
ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myClick();

            }
        });


TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
tv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myClick();

            }
        });
```